# Save/convert .applescript as .scpt

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to convert .applescript files to compiled .scpt files?
I am currently using [AppleScript-Sublime-Text](https://github.com/idleberg/AppleScript-Sublime-Text) to edit my AppleScripts in Sublime Text, and to run them (using Cmd-B).

But I was wondering, is there a way to also save the files to a .scpt file from within Sublime Text?

If not, I still need to open up Script Editor to generate a compiled version, if I want to use it as a Script Library.

Comment: I've updated the package and you can now choose you're preferred build system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osacompile`. Instructions are here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/osacompile.1.html

Comment: (and one can also script Script-Editor which has commands for such actions)

Comment: unfortunately, the link 404s - and searching for `osacompile` on Apple Developer returns [_zero_ links](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=osacompile); seems like Apple keeps dropping support for good stuff :-/